# C# Make Verticalscroll bar Invisible but working

Tags: c#, scrollbar

i have a form and it spreads vertically, my vertical scroll bar is set to true, i need it to be invisible,hidden,.... but keep it working at the same time.
Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you get this working, this is almost certainly a terrible idea from a UX/UI perspective.

Comment: for my design it suits it perfectly

Comment: It might to you, but I am also assuming WinForms / WPF and there is just basically no way that could make sense objectively. You might make a question of it on the UX board, as I'd love to be proven wrong...